# POST/PUT Multi-dimensional array into REST Request

Tags: php, rest, zend-framework2

I need to send some user data for saving through a ZF2 REST. I am sending data in application/x-www-form-urlencoded form like that

```
username=test&first_name=test1&last_name=test2
```

Now I need to add some array data like

```
array ( 0 => array('id' => 123, name => 'test' ), 1 => array('id' => 124, name => 'test1' ));
```

Now I only using application/x-www-form-urlencoded for all of my other requests So I do not prefer any approach other than it as that will lead to changes all code also. So only solution I am thinking of sending data in standard POST Array format like

```
username=test&first_name=test1&last_name=test2&fields[0][id]=123&fields[0][name]=test&fields[1][id]=124&fields[1][name]=test1
```

Other solutions I am thinking of serialize or json-encoded string sending in fields parameter. But looking for any better solution.

Comment: use `serialize` its better.

Comment: @YogeshSuthar you are right, json_encode($array); will do the trick and post it